# how to jsf tags are working in OSGI freamework

Tags: jsf, osgi, equinox

I'm new in osgi framework(Equinox). I use Eclipse kepler version. I succesfully deployed my MyFaces and dependency bundles to equinox. My MyFaces bundle is "myfaces-bundle-2.1.18-SNAPSHOT.jar". My dependency bundle has web.xml file, MANIFEST.MF file and index.xhtml. When i try to run it, i can't see Jsf tags like "h:" or "f:". Only pure html tags are working properly. What am i missing?

Here is my web.xml file;

```
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Here is my MANIFEST.MF file;

```
             .
             .
             .
             .
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes/
Import-Package: javax.el,
 javax.faces.component;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 javax.faces.component.behavior;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 javax.faces.component.html;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 javax.faces.component.visit;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 javax.servlet,
 javax.servlet.http,
 javax.servlet.jsp,
 javax.servlet.jsp.el,
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext,
 org.apache.commons.beanutils;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.commons.codec;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.commons.collections;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.commons.digester;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.config.element;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.elements;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.shared.taglib;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.shared.taglib.core;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT",
 org.apache.myfaces.taglib.html;version="2.1.18.SNAPSHOT"
Web-ContextPath: /TestWeb
```

And here is my index.xhtml file;

```
                .
                .
                .

    <html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

    <h:head>
        Test JSF
        <h:outputText value="TEST!!!" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
      <h:outputText value="Hello World!" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I want to see "Hello World!" and "TEST!!!" outputs. But only see "Test JSF". 
Tags are not working.